# iccube: how to define hierarchy dimension with intermediate table

Tags: olap, iccube

I am newbie, and can't find  how to define dimension for such structure:

```
invoices:
--------
id
id_company
date

invoices_data:
-------------
id
id_invoice
id_product
amount
price

companies:
----------
id
caption
```

How to define companies dimension and link it to invoices_data table?

Answer (score 2):

If possible I'd change the table structure. Note, it's possible to create an iccube table from an SQL statement.

I'd start by creating a few dimensions :

- Company -> using 'companies' ; Multi-Levels just one level with id &
  caption.
- Date -> Use the Time (Wizard); add a start/end matching the data
  you've.
- Product -> using 'invoices_data' : Multi-Levels just one level with
  id_product for both key & name

If possible I'd add the date to the 'invoice_data', SQL join. If no you can create a Many-2-Many table (advanced) that will do the join for you. More info [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_many2many.php), I would not go for m2m unless really needed as it's an advanced features (read the link carefully).

Create a Cube, add 'Facts' with table 'invoice data'. Click on the last button 'Wizard' this will link all dimensions automatically. Eventually add your measures (amount & price).

And that should be it.

hope it helps